# Emgu.CV Capture class throws exception

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to create a WPF app that will allow me to click through a video frame by frame. I'm using the Emgu.CV frameworks Capture class. I can click though 20 to 30 frame and then it stops working.

Basically what I am doing is to click a button which starts the capture, Capture.Start(). In the frame handler I grab the frame and them call Capture.Pause(). I click the buttom again to start the process again. I can do this for awhile and them it stops working. I can play the video all the way through if just start the capture and don't pause it and restart it. 
Here is the code I'm using.

```
    private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        capture = new Capture("C:\\AAAAA\\testVideo.mp4");
        capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
        webCamDisplay.DataContext = webCamManager;
        capture.Start();
    }
    private void btnNextFrame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            capture.Start();
        } catch (Exception ex ) {   
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }
    } 
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg) {
        try {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
            try {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {
                    webCamDisplay.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(frame);
                    webCamManager.Update(frame);
                }));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
            capture.Pause();
        } catch (Exception ex) {                
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }

public class BitmapSourceConvert {
    public static BitmapImage ToBitmapSource(IImage image) {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap) {
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bImg = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            try {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                source.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                bImg.BeginInit();
                bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
                bImg.EndInit();
                return bImg;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                string ms = ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception have you got.

Comment: You have 2 errors

 1) set `bImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`
 2) add `using` to `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()`

Comment: The exception is "A heap has been corrupted". I put in your changes and still get the error. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I also will get an exception of "System.AccessViolationException" on this line, source.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: Remove `using` at this line `using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)`. Because you use `frame` after disposing.
And add `using` at this line `Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();`

Comment: Still having the error. The odd thing is that when running in debug mode none of my exception handlers seem to get hit, the program just seems to stop working. I have to run the program without debugging and then select debugging when it crashes to be able to see what the error is. The problem is I don't know what code is breaking. Thank for you help

Comment: I took out the code to convert the frame to a bitmap and display it. The only code I'm now exercising is the capture code. Starting and stopping the capture seem to be causing the issue.

Comment: I found the problem. I replaced the line capture.Pause with capture.Stop and it is now working. I wish I understood why capture.Pause caused this. It seems like the more obvious method to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` which executes in another thread. Try to put work with `capture` inside `Invoke`

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg) {

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {
              try 
              {
                using(var frame = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame())
                {
                          webCamDisplay.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(frame);
                          webCamManager.Update(frame);
                }
                capture.Pause();
              } 
              catch (Exception ex) 
              {
                      string msg = ex.Message;
              }
            }));

}
```